# How to find 1 in my string but ignore -1 C#

Tags: c#

I have a string

```
string test1 = "255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";
```

I want to find all the 1's in my string but not the -1's. So in my string there is only one 1. I use `string.Contain("1")` but this will find two 1's. So how do i do this?

Comment: You know that you have to use `string test1 = @"255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";`  if you don't want that the letter n will be interpreted as a new-line?

Comment: try splitting and comparing each element of string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple solution:

**Note : You can convert this to extension Method Easily.**

```
static List<int> FindIndexSpecial(string search, char find, char ignoreIfPreceededBy)
{
    // Map each Character with its Index in the String
    var characterIndexMapping = search.Select((x, y) => new { character = x, index = y }).ToList();
    // Check the Indexes of the excluded Character
    var excludeIndexes = characterIndexMapping.Where(x => x.character == ignoreIfPreceededBy).Select(x => x.index).ToList();

    // Return only Indexes who match the 'find' and are not preceeded by the excluded character
    return (from t in characterIndexMapping
            where t.character == find && !excludeIndexes.Contains(t.index - 1)
            select t.index).ToList();
}
```

Usage :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string test1 = "255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";

    var matches = FindIndexSpecial(test1, '1', '-');
    foreach (int index in matches)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(index);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *regular expression*:

```
  string test1 = "255\r\n\r\n0\r\n\r\n-1\r\n\r\n255\r\n\r\n1\r";

  // if at least one "1", but not "-1"
  if (Regex.IsMatch(test1, "(?<!-)1")) {
    ...
  }
```

the pattern is exactly `1` which is not preceed by `-`. To find *all* the 1s:

```
 var matches = Regex
   .Matches(test1, "(?<!-)1") 
   .OfType<Match>()
   .ToArray(); // if you want an array
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.Split` and `Enumerable.Contains` or `Enumerable.Where`:

```
string[] lines = test1.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine, "\r"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
bool contains1 = lines.Contains("1");
string[] allOnes = lines.Where(l => l == "1").ToArray();
```

`String.Contains` searches for sub-strings in a given string instance. `Enumerable.Contains` looks if there's at least one string in the `string[]` which equals it.